# Trying to combine 2 variables for one output (jquery)

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to display 1 of 5 messages at random. I have everything working except i'm trying to dynamically call a variable by combining 2 other variables. See below

```
var note1 = "boo";
var note2 = "quack";
var note3 = "bark";
var note4 = "meow";
var note5 = "moo";

//generate number between 1-5
var rnumber = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
var note;

$( ".site-notification" ).hide("slow", function(){
    $(".service-offered").html(note+rnumber);//i want this to output the note1-5's     content
});
```

is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `note` is never initialized with a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the global window object to do this easily:

```
$(".service-offered").html(window['note'+rnumber]);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/A2D2w/)**

Comment: This was perfect! not even sure how it works differently from what i was trying to do but awesome!

Comment: In your code `note` was being treated as a variable instead of a string, but moreover it wasn't using the window object.

Answer (score 4):

how about using an array?

```
var notes = ["boo", "quack", "bark", "meow", "moo"];
```

And then to get a random note:

```
$(".service-offered").html(notes[rnumber]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This wont work as this is interpreted as a calculation or string linkage.
Try to put the messages in an array and then call an element of that array with a random key.
Example follows...

Well, there already are examples :)

Answer (score 0):

Make the notes into an array

```
var notes = [
    "boo",
    "quack",
    "bark",
    "meow",
    "moo"
];
```

Then randomly select an element

```
$sel.html(notes[Math.floor(Math.random() * notes.length]));
```